# Regular Expression to match #hashtag but not #hashtag; (with semicolon)

Tags: regex, hashtag

I have the current regular expression:

```
/(?<=[\s>]|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)/g
```

Which I'm testing against the string:

```
Here's a #hashtag and here is #not_a_tag; which should be different. Also testing: Mid#hash. #123 #!@£ and <p>#hash</p>
```

For my purposes there should only be two hashtags detected in this string. I'm wondering how to alter the expression such that it **doesn't** match hashtags that end with a `;` in my example this is `#not_a_tag;`

Cheers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about the following:

```
\B(\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP6yX5/1)

- \B -> Not a word boundary
- (#[a-zA-Z]+\b) -> Capturing Group beginning with # followed by any number of a-z or A-Z with a word boundary at the end
- (?!;) -> Not followed by ;

Comment: Did you mean `\B`? `\W` needs an actual character to be present before the `#`.

Comment: Accepted answer for least steps. \B is likely what I'll be using.

Comment: It does not match #007 nor #50cents which are real hashtags.

Comment: Does it support non-English languages?

Answer (score 11):

This is the best practice.

```
(#+[a-zA-Z0-9(_)]{1,})
```

Comment: Best answer on here, thank you. Only modification that may be needed is to allow åççéñts if your software will be international. Maybe something like `(#+[a-zA-Z0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ʸ(_)]{1,})`

Comment: Perfect, but ####tag is also valid. UPD: `^#[a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯÀ-ÖØ-öø-ʸ0-9(_)]{1,}$`

Comment: Why does this answer include brackets `()` as a valid hashtag character? Also why does it allow multiple hashtags like ##hashtag? Also why is `{1,}` used, if a simple `+` would be sufficient?

Answer (score 9):

```
/(#(?:[^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)/g
```

Starts with #, then at least one (+) ANCII symbols ([^\x00-\x7F], range excluding non-ANCII symbols) or word symbol (\w).

This one should cover cases including ANCII symbols like "#їжак".

Answer (score 4):

You can use a negative lookahead reegex:

```
/(?<=[\s>]|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)\b(?!;)/
```

- `\b` - word boundary ensures that we are at end of word
- `(?!;)` - asserts that we don't have semi-colon at next position

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC9dA3/1)

Comment: For performance `\B#(\d*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)\b(?!;)` should be your regex. `#[a-zA-Z]+` won't match `#123hashtag`

Comment: Plus, turned out, 'look behind regex' is not supported for Safari.

Comment: Yes that's right, it was never meant to be Safari compatible though

Answer (score 1):

Similar to anubhava's answer but swap the 2 instances of `\w*` with `\d*` as the only difference between `\w` and `[A-Za-z_]` is the `0-9` characters

This has the effect of reducing the number of steps from 588 to 90

`(?<=[\s>])#(\d*[A-Za-z_]+\d*)\b(?!;)`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP8aW8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern : `/#\S+/`

It will include all characters after `#` except for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=(\s|^))#[^\s\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)]+(?=(\s|$))
```

A regex code that matches any hashtag.

In this approach any character is accepted in hashtags except main signs `!@#$%^&*()`

**Usage Notes**

Turn on "g" and "m" flags when using!

It is tested for Java and JavaScript languages via https://regex101.com and VSCode tools.

It is available on [this repo](https://github.com/mbscreater/hashtag_regex).

Comment: Don't think your answer is answering OP questions: https://regex101.com/r/FFvPfn/1 OP doesn't want to match the semicolon. For the future it's better to share direct regex101 demo/snippet instead of just link to the landing page.