# Regex for a valid hashtag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regular expression for validating a hashtag. Each hashtag should starts with hashtag("#").

Valid inputs:

`1. #hashtag_abc`

`2. #simpleHashtag`

`3. #hashtag123`

Invalid inputs:

`1. #hashtag#`

`2. #hashtag@hashtag`

I have been trying with this regex `/#[a-zA-z0-9]/` but it is accepting invalid inputs also.

Any suggestions for how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To answer the current question...**

There are 2 issues:

- `[A-z]` [allows more than just letter chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) (`` [, , ], ^, _, ` `` )
- There is no quantifier after the character class and it only matches 1 char

Since you are *validating* the whole string, you also need anchors (`^` and `$`)to ensure a full string match:

```js
/^#\w+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lmsipc/1).

**If you want to extract specific valid hashtags from longer texts...**

This is a bonus section as a lot of people seek to extract (not validate) hashtags, so here are a couple of solutions for you. Just mind that `\w` in JavaScript (and a lot of other regex libraries) equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

- `#\w{1,30}\b` - a `#` char followed with one to thirty word chars followed with a word boundary
- `\B#\w{1,30}\b` - a `#` char that is either at the start of string or right after a non-word char, then one to thirty word (i.e. letter, digit, or underscore) chars followed with one to thirty word chars followed with a word boundary
- `\B#(?![\d_]+\b)(\w{1,30})\b` - `#` that is either at the start of string or right after a non-word char, then one to thirty word (i.e. letter, digit, or underscore) chars (that cannot be just digits/underscores) followed with a word boundary

And last but not least, here is a ***Twitter hashtag regex*** from https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js... Sorry, too long to paste in the SO post, here it is: https://gist.github.com/stribizhev/715ee1ee2dc1439ffd464d81d22f80d1.

Comment: Your current expression won't match OP's first valid input as it contains an underscore.

Comment: @Niitaku: Yes, you are right, the pattern should be much simpler then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew here is one more valid input  `#hashtag123`

Comment: @Ashok: Yes, it will get matched with `/^#\w+$/` as `#` matches a hash symbol, the `\w+` matches 1+ ASCII letters, digits or `_`. And the anchors require a full string match. See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lmsipc/2).

Answer (score 17):

The current accepted answer fails in a few places:

- It accepts hashtags that have no letters in them (i.e. "#11111", "#___" both pass).
- It will exclude hashtags that are separated by spaces ("hey there #friend" fails to match "#friend").
- It doesn't allow you to place a min/max length on the hashtag.
- It doesn't offer a lot of flexibility if you decide to add other symbols/characters to your valid input list.

Try the following regex:

```
/(^|\B)#(?![0-9_]+\b)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,30})(\b|\r)/g
```

It'll close up the above edge cases, and furthermore:

- You can change {1,30} to your desired min/max
- You can add other symbols to the [0-9_] and [a-zA-Z0-9_] blocks if you wish to later

Here's a [link to the demo](https://regex101.com/r/78GYyD/5).

Comment: I guess nobody cares about the first and last capturing group, so i would change them using a non capturing group: `(?:^|\B)`

Comment: this one doesnt handle unicode at all.  the world is not nato alphabet... it also doesn't handle cases like `#invalid#invalid #invalid@ invalid#invalid ##invalid`

Answer (score 1):

Unicode general categories can help with that task:

```
/^#[\p{L}\p{Nd}_]+$/gu
```

I use \p{L} and \p{Nd} unicode categories to match any letter or decimal digit number. You can add any necessary category for your regex. The complete list of categories can be found here: https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property

Regex live demo:
https://regexr.com/5tvmo

Answer (score 0):

You could try the this : `/#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/`

This will only include letters, numbers & underscores.

Comment: This regex accept a space just after `#` or `#######`

Comment: @Toto I removed the dot(`.`) before `\S` not it doesn't accepts the spaces after `#`.

Comment: True, but it always matches `#*%$£;,`, not sure it's a valid hashtag.

Comment: If you want to limit it only for characters use `#\w+`.

Comment: OK, but, now, how is it better than other answers?

Answer (score 0):

A regex code that matches any hashtag.

In this approach any character is accepted in hashtags except main signs !@#$%^&*()

```
(?<=(\s|^))#[^\s\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)]+(?=(\s|$))
```

## **Usage Notes**

Turn on "g" and "m" flags when using!

It is tested for Java and JavaScript languages via https://regex101.com and VSCode tools.

It is available on [this repo](https://github.com/mbscreater/hashtag_regex).

Comment: Please, don't give twice [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67035964/372239), mark the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**useful and tested regex for detecting hashtags in the text**

```
/(^|\s)(#[a-zA-Z\d_]+)/ig
```

examples of valid matching hashtag:
*#abc
#ab_c
#ABC
#aBC*

Answer (score 0):

`/\B(?:#|＃)((?![\p{N}_]+(?:$|\b|\s))(?:[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]{1,60}))/ug`

- allow any language characters or characters with numbers or `_`.
- numbers alone or numbers with `_`  are not allowed.

It's unicode regex, so if you are using Python, you may need to install [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

to test it https://regex101.com/r/NLHUQh/1