# Use RegEx to validate a hashtag string in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textbox in my app where people can insert tags they want to associate with something.
I'm not a regex wizard, so i searched around for solutions, and i fond this:

`/^#\w+$/` [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065872/regex-for-a-valid-hashtag)

It works great with a string containing only one tag e.g `"#something"`, but fails to work for 
`"#some1 #some2"`,
Im using the `.match()` function in javascript to check the validity of the string.

How can i write it so it works for these examples:

- `"#tag1"`
- `"#tag1 #tag2 "`
- `"#tag_space #tagNoSpace #numbres456!"`

But fails for these:

- `"#first #"` - no chars after *#*
- `"#first second"` - no *#* on second phrase
- `""` - empty
- `"tag"` - no *#* on phrase
- `"#second#first"` - not space between phrases
- `"#this_has_a_#_in_it"` - has a *#* in the phrase

Is There any way this can be done?

Comment: to everyone voting negative, please explain why you vote negative so that the question can be improved.

Comment: Try it like this `^#[^#\s]+(?: #[^#\s]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/G2CmMR/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/QnG368/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use anchors, you could match the hashtag followed by matching not a whitespace or a hashtag. Then repeat the match 0 or more times preceded by a space using a non capturing group `(?:`

The pattern might look like:

```
^#[^#\s]+(?: #[^#\s]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2CmMR/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern slightly so any (a) word character (`\w`) or digit (`\d`) can comprise your hashtag:

```
/^#[\w\d]+$/
```