In a Python regex (re), how can I match the start of a string (^) OR a non-alphanumeric character (\W)?
I am using the Python regex package re for example to match a hashtag or url.  A hashtag starts with a #, which cannot be in the middle of a word.  Hence, it can be at the start of a word, which I can find with \W OR at the start of the string (^).  How can I catch both cases, i.e. ^ OR \W?  I tried things like (b for my bytes-like object)
hashtag = rb'[^|\W]#\w*'

and all kinds of variation trying to escape ^, leaving out |, using \b, etc.
Another example would be an url, which starts with "http(s)://":
url = rb'[^|\W]https?:\/\/\w*'

How can this be done?  Note that I am using Python, not Javascript!

Like \B#\w+ See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065872/regex-for-a-valid-hashtag

@Thefourthbird Thanks a lot, that works.  I hadn't realised I should have searched for Javascript when looking for Python solutions.  Would you like to turn this into an answer?

The page that has been marked as duplicate already answers it.

@Thefourthbird I'm not sure that matching a hashtag in Javascript is the same as matching the beginning of a string or the beginning of a word in Python.  I clarified that the hashtag is one example, but I want the same for urls (where \B doesn't seem to work, and I don't understand why).  I also clarified that I am using Python, not Javascript.

Here are some solutions using Python where you can see the difference in matches \B#\w+ https://regex101.com/r/rL0YAt/1 OR (?<!\S)#\w+ https://regex101.com/r/sm1IRG/1 OR (?:^|\s)(#\w+) https://regex101.com/r/ibItWT/1 OR (?<!\S)#\w+(?!\S) https://regex101.com/r/UjERLK/1 OR (?<!\S)#[^\s#]+(?!\S) https://regex101.com/r/4gdsde/1

You seem to be confusing [] with ().

Here not mention some example.
According to my understanding, need to match http/https URLs procede by a non-word or at start position.
So, regex should be:
     rb'(?:(?<=\W)|(?<=^))https?:\/\/\S+'

